# Perform calculation on Ecto result

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to perform calculation on Ecto result.  I have a Products table, which have `(color, rating, brand_id, price)`.  I want to group the rating by `range (0-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5)` and count of products in each range.  I'm quite new to elixir, and ecto.  All help appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your initial effort.

Comment: Depending on the DB, I'd guess this is probably easier to do on the DB side than on the Elixir side.  If I were you I'd be looking for a SQL query to create the ranges you want.

Comment: because i also want to group by brand_id, and get count of products in each brand_id, and group by price as well.  I'm not sure if there's a way to do that in 1 query. so i'm thinking it's better to query for all products and perform calculation to get result of each group

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way that just uses `floor` to get the rating range lower bound:

```
defmodule QueryHelpers
  @doc "floor function for postgres"
  defmacro floor(x) do
    quote do 
      fragment("floor(?)", unquote(x))
    end
  end
end

defmodule A
  import QueryHelpers

  def product_rating_counts() do
    from product in Product, 
    group_by: floor(product.rating),
    select: %{rating: floor(product.rating), count: count(1)}),
    order_by: [asc: 1]
  end
end

iex> Repo.all(A.product_rating_counts())
[%{count: 2, rating: #Decimal<1>}, 
 %{count: 1, rating: #Decimal<2>},
 %{count: 1, rating: #Decimal<4>}]
```

Comment: is there a way to do group_by and count on multiple columns in a single query? because i want to group and product count on brand_id, color, and price as well